# How can i have my own signaling_server with internet

Tags: sockets, server

Hello i created a WebRTC screen-sharing on my website, and i just wanted to create and have my own signaling server in case that the one present on the code would ('https://socketio-over-nodejs2.herokuapp.com:443/') be not functional in the future although i need a server using internet (not localhost:...) 
How can i process ? Thanks

```
var config = {

openSocket: function (config) {
var SIGNALING_SERVER = 'https://socketio-over-nodejs2.herokuapp.com:443/';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go on AWS and start up a remote machine for free (be sure to pick one in a country near you). 
Then remote onto your server, install node.js, and put the signalling server code into an index.js file in a folder somewhere. Then go to the directory in commmand prompt, type `npm install` to install any dependencies, then `node index.js` to run your server. Be sure to open up the correct port on your remote machine.

See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#6
for example code of a node.js signalling server.